# How Exceptions are handle in EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have written following code for exception handling of EJB.

1)Module.java

```
`@WebService(serviceName = "Module")
@Stateless()
public class Module {
    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public int hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) throws Exception {
        int re=0;
        try{
            re=(6/0);     
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw (EJBException) new EJBException(se).initCause(e);
        }
        return re;;
        }
    }
}`
```

2)
Client.jsp

```
`<%
try{
    selec.Module_Service service = new selec.Module_Service();
    selec.Module port = service.getModulePort();
    java.lang.String name = "";
    int result = port.hello(name);
    out.println("Result = "+result);
}catch(EJBException e){
    Exception ee=(Exception)e.getCause();
    if(ee.getClass().getName().equals("Exception")){
       System.out.println("Database error: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
%>`
```

Inside catch block Exception object ee get me as null.
What is an issue that it give me null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the recommended method to retrieve the root-cause exceptions from an EJB. [`EJBException#getCausedBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBException.html) is the recommended method for getting the root exception on an EJB.

According to the API however, it's even better if you get the cause from `Throwable#getCause`. So what you should have is

```
Exception ee= ((Throwable)e).getCause();
```

Comment: the cast to Throwable is redundant

Comment: I think so too , but for some reason, the doc deems it preferable somehow. I added that option only for completeness @SteveC